# How to draw a rectangle box and put something inside that box?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to see both box and object inside the box using three.js;
when I'm trying with cubeGeometry:

```
var cubeMaterials = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({wireframe:true,wireframeLinewidth:8,}  );
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 100, 100, 100, 1, 1, 1 );
cube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, cubeMaterials );
```

Still there are lines of triangle. I don't want that. Actually I'm trying to draw one rack and place some object in that rack.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use the `boxHelper`, that draws a wireframe without face diagonals: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Helpers/BoxHelper

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating what you want, using the `boxHelper`: http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/26/

Comment: thanks for reply .but when i use boxhelper .i cant use an objects all properties like heigt,and i cant move that object to

Comment: You can retrieve the size from the boxHelpers bounding box and move it by translating the geometry.

Comment: i need to drag and drop the object .if it a object i will use thi code and find the intersection point

Comment: raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
        //find all intesected object//if raycaster is using then below code
        //var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(lesson10.objects);//this also correct
        intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects); //doubt object or scene.children